# How to fix ParserError: Error tokenizing data for CSV pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Sample DF(1 column without header name):

```
vers    2.1.0  
info    days    6
info    x       a
info    y       b
```

Here is my code and error message:

```
df = pd.read_csv("64881_info.csv")
```

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error
```

I tried to fix:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("64881_info.csv", error_bad_lines=False)
```

It works but column header name shift right by next. Row indexing is not showing also after reading the csv file. How can I fix this?

Output df:

```
        vers    2.1.0
info    days    6     
info    x       a
info    y       b
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of this csv file? You say "Row indexing is not showing" but I don't understand what that means. The last table you share is also confusing. What is that? The output of your dataframe after the failed import?

Comment: I have given a sample df,  "Row indexing is not showing" which means when we read a df in pandas, output shows along with row indexing in notebook. But here It is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After resetting row indexing, it works!

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

output:

```
    index   vers    2.1.0
0   info    days    6
1   info    x       a
2   info    y       b
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to just skip the bad lines if you don't think there are too many:

df= pd.read_csv('64881_info.csv', on_bad_lines='skip')